# Dockerized Selenium Webscrapper not behaving the same locally and on server

Tags: python, linux, docker, selenium-webdriver

I am running 3 docker container, they are all located in a folder called rpdef.

This is my project architecture:

> rpdef/db/db.sql (contains database script)
>
> rpdef/rpdef-api (contains API logic)
>
> rpdef/scrape-and-calculate (contains python files for my Selenium web
> scrapper)
>
> rpdef/scrape-and-calculate/Dockerfile
>
> rpdef/docker-compose.yml

This is my rpdef/docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rpdef
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db/db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql

  rpdef-api:
    build: ./rpdef-api
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DB: rpdef

  scrape-and-calculate:
    build: ./scrape-and-calculate
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"    
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DB: rpdef
```

This is my rpdef/scrape-and-calculate/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
   wget  && \
   apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
   wget  && \
   unzip  && \
   mv chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver && \
   rm -rf  chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I run docker compose up and python on my local machine everything works fine, but when I run it on a linux server I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>

header, teams_defense = scrape.team_defenses(season)

File "/app/scrape.py", line 113, in team_defenses

table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz')

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 830, in find_element

return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute

self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Crom_table__p1iZz"}

(Session info: chrome-headless-shell=122.0.6261.94)

Stacktrace:

0 0x55ce9b9fcd93 <unknown> 1 0x55ce9b6e0337 <unknown> 2 0x55ce9b72bd60 <unknown> 3 0x55ce9b72be51 <unknown> 4 0x55ce9b76fbc4 <unknown> 5 0x55ce9b74e46d <unknown> 6 0x55ce9b76d12d <unknown> 7 0x55ce9b74e1e3 <unknown> 8 0x55ce9b71e135 <unknown> 9 0x55ce9b71f13e <unknown> 10 0x55ce9b9c0e4b <unknown> 11 0x55ce9b9c4dfa <unknown> 12 0x55ce9b9ad6d5 <unknown> 13 0x55ce9b9c5a6f <unknown> 14 0x55ce9b99169f <unknown> 15 0x55ce9b9ea098 <unknown> 16 0x55ce9b9ea262 <unknown> 17 0x55ce9b9fbf34 <unknown> 18 0x7fdb7d7d8ea7 start_thread
```

This error happens, because the `webscrapper` opens a website that doesn't have an element with selector: "Crom_table__p1iZz". This error showed before when I was trying to run locally, but I fixed it with installation of correct `google-chrome` and `Chromedriver` versions and using a custom user-agent.

The google-chrome and `Chromedriver` versions are the same on docker locally and on server docker.

As far as I understand this should work the same if the docker containers are running on my local machine or on a Linux server, but they are not running and behaving the same. Why is that and how do I fix this?

Here is my driver configuration and method that is webscrapping:

```
def team_defenses(season):
    url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/defense?Season=' + season
  
    driver = get_web_driver()

    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the table to load, if it doesn't load display content
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz')))
    except:
        with open('error_page_source.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(driver.page_source)

    # Find the table element
    table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz')

    # Find all rows in the table
    rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
    team_defenses = []
    # Loop through each row and extract the data from each cell
    for row in rows:
        i=0
        # Find all cells in the row
        cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
        team=''
        def_rtg = 0
        opp_pts_paint = 0
        for cell in cells:
            if i==1:
                team = cell.text
            elif i==6:
                def_rtg = float(cell.text)
            elif i==14:
                opp_pts_paint = float(cell.text)
            i+=1
        if team:
            team_defenses.append([get_team_abbrivation(team), def_rtg, opp_pts_paint])
    header = ['Team', 'DEF', 'RDEF']
    return header, team_defenses

def get_web_driver():
    header = Headers(
        browser="chrome",  # Generate only Chrome UA
        os="win",  # Generate only Windows platform
        headers=False # generate misc headers
    )
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    customUserAgent = header.generate()['User-Agent']
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={customUserAgent}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        options=chrome_options
    )
    return driver
```

Any help is very much appriciated.